# How to customize dynamic_sidebar rendering?

Tags: widgets

I have an sidebar and a text widget in it. i need to customize the content of text widget rendering on that sidebar.

Comment: Just do it. What is your specific problem?

Comment: i need to add wrappers and title tag of my own choice.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add all the details, and don't forget to show us what you have tried already See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You may add before as well as after class to the sidebar when you define it into functions.php.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'unique-sidebar-id',
    'description'   => '',
        'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">', //You can change class/id here
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' ); ?>
```

Comment: You can refer this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/